# Android Parse Facebook Login JSON Null

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

When I have a new user login through facebook on my app, I make a `newMeRequest` in order to grab information about the new user.
This code use to be working fine, but lately I've noticed that almost all new user `signups through facebook` on my app have been lacking required data I was pulling from facebook.

I noticed that the JSON I get from the `newMeRequest` is sometimes turning out to be `null` (I've been running the code on a test database using my facebook profile over and over and deleting my account to do another test iteration) and `sometimes it's not null.`

Additionally I have been having issues lately with the app saying `Uh oh. The User canceled the Facebook Login`, but this too doesn't happen 100% of the time.

Code portion of "Uh oh....":

```
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (user == null) {
                Log.d(Application.TAG, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else if (user.isNew()) {
                Log.d(Application.TAG, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                updateUserInfo();
                showNewFBActivity();
            } else {
                Log.d(Application.TAG, "User logged in through Facebook!");
                startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, DispatchActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the code running the Request:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();

                // Fill in profile data.....

            } else if (graphResponse.getError() != null) {
                switch (graphResponse.getError().getCategory()) {
                    case LOGIN_RECOVERABLE:
                        Log.d(Application.TAG,
                                "Authentication error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                        break;

                    case TRANSIENT:
                        Log.d(Application.TAG,
                                "Transient error. Try again. " + graphResponse.getError());
                        break;

                    case OTHER:
                        Log.d(Application.TAG,
                                "Some other error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                        break;
                }
```

When it is null I print out this error:

Some other error:

```
{HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to graph.facebook.com/31.13.70.1 (port 443): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)}
```

Here is my Manifest and my Gradle if that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.juryroom.qollege_android_v1" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Needed for Parse Push -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.juryroom.qollege_android_v1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.juryroom.qollege_android_v1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<!-- To get picture from Camera -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/qollege_icon"
    android:label="Qollege"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name=".DispatchActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

         .... More Activities....

</application>
```

Gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '#######################'
            keyPassword '##################'
            storeFile file('#############################')
            storePassword '#########################'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.juryroom.qollege_android_v1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



repositories { 
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')

    .............. MORE.......................
}
```

Comment: Please file a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs